# Mathematica does not solve all the variable in linear solve. Why?

Tags: equation-solving

The below coding contains 9 equations and 9 unknowns.  But I have errors every time like "Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables." Does not seem my program is wrong.

```
solution=Solve[{-(1/2) I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]2p-(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]2p)/2-(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]mp)/2+(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]mp)/2+(I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]p2)/2+(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]p2)/2+(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]pm)/2-(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]pm)/2+I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]mp Sin[\[Phi]]+I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]pm Sin[\[Phi]]==0,
-(1/2) I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]2m+(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]2m)/2+(I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]m2)/2-(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]m2)/2+(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]mp)/2-(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]mp)/2-(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]pm)/2+(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]pm)/2-I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]mp Sin[\[Phi]]-I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]pm Sin[\[Phi]]==0,
\[Rho]pp+\[Rho]mm+\[Rho]22==1,
(I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]22)/2-(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]22)/2+(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]2m)/2+(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]2m)/2+(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]2p)/2-(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]2p)/2-(I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]mm)/2+(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]mm)/2-(I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]pm)/2-(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]pm)/2-I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]2m Cos[\[Phi]]-I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]2p Sin[\[Phi]]==0,
-(1/2) I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]22+(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]22)/2-(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]m2)/2-(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]m2)/2+(I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]mm)/2-(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]mm)/2+(I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]mp)/2+(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]mp)/2-(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]p2)/2+(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]p2)/2+I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]m2 Cos[\[Phi]]-I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]p2 Sin[\[Phi]]==0,
-(1/2) I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]2m-(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]2m)/2-(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]mm)/2+(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]mm)/2+(I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]p2)/2-(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]p2)/2+(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]pp)/2-(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]pp)/2-2 I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]pm Cos[\[Phi]]+I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]mm Sin[\[Phi]]-I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]pp Sin[\[Phi]]==0,
-(1/2) I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]2p+(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]2p)/2+(I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]m2)/2+(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]m2)/2+(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]mm)/2-(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]mm)/2-(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]pp)/2+(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]pp)/2+2 I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]mp Cos[\[Phi]]+I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]mm Sin[\[Phi]]-I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]pp Sin[\[Phi]]==0,
(I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]22)/2+(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]22)/2+(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]2m)/2-(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]2m)/2+(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]2p)/2+(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]2p)/2-(I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]mp)/2+(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]mp)/2-(I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]pp)/2-(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]pp)/2+I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]2p Cos[\[Phi]]+I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]2m Sin[\[Phi]]==0,
-(1/2) I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]22-(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]22)/2-(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]m2)/2+(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]m2)/2-(I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]p2)/2-(I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]p2)/2+(I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]pm)/2-(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]pm)/2+(I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]pp)/2+(I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]pp)/2-I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]p2 Cos[\[Phi]]+I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]m2 Sin[\[Phi]]==0},{\[Rho]22,\[Rho]pp,\[Rho]mm,\[Rho]pm,\[Rho]mp,\[Rho]2p,\[Rho]p2,\[Rho]m2,\[Rho]2m}]
```

Answer (score 3):

The determinant of coefficient matrix of the linear system is zero, therefore  you can't hope to solve all variables.

```
Det[Coefficient[#, {\[Rho]22, \[Rho]pp, \[Rho]mm, \[Rho]pm, \[Rho]mp, \
\[Rho]2p, \[Rho]p2, \[Rho]m2, \[Rho]2m}] & /@ 
   First /@ {-(1/2) I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]2p - (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]2p)/
        2 - (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]mp)/2 + (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]mp)/
        2 + (I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]p2)/2 + (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]p2)/
        2 + (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]pm)/2 - (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]pm)/2 + 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]mp Sin[\[Phi]] + 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]pm Sin[\[Phi]] == 
      0, -(1/2) I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]2m + (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]2m)/
        2 + (I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]m2)/2 - (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]m2)/
        2 + (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]mp)/2 - (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]mp)/
        2 - (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]pm)/2 + (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]pm)/2 - 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]mp Sin[\[Phi]] - 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]pm Sin[\[Phi]] == 
      0, \[Rho]pp + \[Rho]mm + \[Rho]22 == 
      1, (I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]22)/2 - (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]22)/
        2 + (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]2m)/2 + (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]2m)/
        2 + (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]2p)/2 - (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]2p)/
        2 - (I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]mm)/2 + (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]mm)/
        2 - (I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]pm)/2 - (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]pm)/2 - 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]2m Cos[\[Phi]] - 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]2p Sin[\[Phi]] == 
      0, -(1/2) I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]22 + (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]22)/
        2 - (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]m2)/2 - (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]m2)/
        2 + (I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]mm)/2 - (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]mm)/
        2 + (I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]mp)/2 + (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]mp)/
        2 - (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]p2)/2 + (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]p2)/2 + 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]m2 Cos[\[Phi]] - 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]p2 Sin[\[Phi]] == 
      0, -(1/2) I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]2m - (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]2m)/
        2 - (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]mm)/2 + (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]mm)/
        2 + (I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]p2)/2 - (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]p2)/
        2 + (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]pp)/2 - (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]pp)/2 - 
       2 I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]pm Cos[\[Phi]] + 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]mm Sin[\[Phi]] - 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]pp Sin[\[Phi]] == 
      0, -(1/2) I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]2p + (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]2p)/
        2 + (I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]m2)/2 + (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]m2)/
        2 + (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]mm)/2 - (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]mm)/
        2 - (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]pp)/2 + (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]pp)/2 + 
       2 I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]mp Cos[\[Phi]] + 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]mm Sin[\[Phi]] - 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]pp Sin[\[Phi]] == 
      0, (I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]22)/2 + (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]22)/
        2 + (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]2m)/2 - (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]2m)/
        2 + (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]2p)/2 + (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]2p)/
        2 - (I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]mp)/2 + (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]mp)/
        2 - (I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]pp)/2 - (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]pp)/2 + 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]2p Cos[\[Phi]] + 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]2m Sin[\[Phi]] == 
      0, -(1/2) I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]22 - (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]22)/
        2 - (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]m2)/2 + (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]m2)/
        2 - (I \[Delta]1 \[Rho]p2)/2 - (I \[Delta]3 \[Rho]p2)/
        2 + (I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]pm)/2 - (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]pm)/
        2 + (I \[Alpha]12 \[Rho]pp)/2 + (I \[Alpha]23 \[Rho]pp)/2 - 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]p2 Cos[\[Phi]] + 
       I \[Alpha]13 \[Rho]m2 Sin[\[Phi]] == 0}] // Expand
```

(*0 *)